# Has my Ubuntu been deleted?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I was running Ubuntu 12.04 as an only OS on my laptop in 250 GB out of 500 GB. I decided to install windows 7 alongside. While installing it, I chose 'unallocated 250 GB' as a location where to install windows. After installing it, I cannot access my Ubuntu. I have tried boot-repair by booting from Ubuntu LiveUSB but no result. When I check through disk utility I get this:

250 GB: NTFS

248 GB: Unallocated Space.

2 GB: Unknown

Does this mean my Ubuntu is erased? Is there a way to access my data again?

Please help.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately it seems like that may be the case.  Boot a live cd/usb, open a terminal, and type `sudo fdisk -l`.  If you don't see an ext3/ext4 partition, then it's very likely that your Ubuntu was deleted. In that case, try installing the utility "testdisk" (from the live session) to see if you can recover anything.  Do not boot Windows or anything except a live cd/usb, doing so may make it even harder to recover data.

Answer (score 0):

The boot loader of Windows (ntloader) didn't detect Ubuntu and hence only showing Windows. You may just have to reinstall the GRUB loader of Ubuntu. see the following link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows